# Liquid templates for transforming json to json in Azure LogicApps

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps

I am new to this Azure liquid templates.  I am having six elements in an json array. Im parsing json to json.

```
{
          "arrayvalues": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "tot": 2,
              "vu": "100",
               "props": [
                {
                  "find": "ghi",
                  "sky": "1000"
                },
                {
                  "find": "ijk",
                  "sky": "1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "tot": 1,
              "vu": "0",
              "props": [
               {
                  "find": "abc",
                  "sky": "500"
                },
                {
                  "find": "ijk",
                  "sky": "2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "tot": 10,
              "vu": "300",
              "props": [
              
                {
                  "find": "abc",
                  "sky": "100"
                },
                {
                  "find": "ijk",
                  "sky": "3"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "tot": 5,
              "vu": "500",
              "props": [
                {
                  "find": "xyz",
                  "sky": "900"
                },
                {
                  "find": "ijk",
                  "sky": "4"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 5,
              "tot": 6,
              "vu": "10000",
              "props": [
                {
                  "find": "xyz",
                  "sky": "00"
                },
                {
                  "find": "ijk",
                  "sky": "5"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 6,
              "tot": 7,
              "vu": "20000",
              "props": [
                {
                  "find": "xyz",
                  "sky": "001"
                },
                {
                  "find": "ijk",
                  "sky": "6"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

1. First i have to check the field called "find". If "find" value is equal to "abc". Then i need to get the "sky" field value(That is 500 and 100 (in 2nd and 3rd lineitems)). and also i need to get the "tot" values for that lineitems (That is "1" and "10" in 2nd and 3 rd lineitems).
2. And i need to map this "sky" values with another lineitems "vu" values. If it is true then output like below(in our scenario 2nd lineitem "sky" value is matching with 4th lineitem "vu" value 500. And 3rd lineitem "sky" value is matching with 1st lineitem "vu" value 100).

   {
   "id": "1",
   "tot": "2",
   "vu": "100",
   "Mark": "Yes",
   "Volume": "10"
   },
   {
   "id": "4",
   "tot": "5",
   "vu": "500",
   "Mark": "Yes",
   "Volume": "1"
   }

(This "Volume" values we are getting from 2nd and 3rd lineitems "tot" values that are 1 and 10).

3.Here there is no "sky" field value is not matching wiyh 5th and 6th lineitems "vu" values(That are 10000 and 20000). So the 5th and 6th lineitems output will be like below:

```
{
          "id": "5",
          "tot": "6",
          "vu": "10000",
          "Mark": "NO",
          "Volume": "0"
        },
        {
        "id": "6",
          "tot": "7",
          "vu": "20000",
          "Mark": "NO",
          "Volume": "0"
        }
```

My total output like below:

```
 {
      "arrayvalues": [
        {
         "id": "1",
          "tot": "2",
          "vu": "100",
          "Mark": "Yes",
          "Volume": "10"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "tot": "1",
          "vu": "0",
          "Mark": "NO",
          "Volume": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "tot": "10",
          "vu": "300",
          "Mark": "NO",
          "Volume": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "tot": "5",
          "vu": "500",
          "Mark": "Yes",
          "Volume": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tot": "6",
          "vu": "10000",
          "Mark": "NO",
          "Volume": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "tot": "7",
          "vu": "20000",
          "Mark": "NO",
          "Volume": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have tried the below code.

```
{% assign sky_name = "" %}
{% assign tot_value = "" %}
{
  "values": [
    {% for i in content.arrayvalues %}
        {% for properties in i.props %}
            {% if properties.find == "abc" %}
            {
            "id" : "{{i.id}}",
            "tot" : "{{i.tot}}",
            "vu" : "{{i.vu}}",
            "Mark" : "NO",
            "Volume" : "0"
            },
            {% assign sky_name = properties.sky %}
            {% assign tot_value = i.tot %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            {% assign vu_name = i.vu %}
            {% if vu_name == sky_name %}
            {
            "id" : "{{i.id}}",
            "tot" : "{{i.tot}}",
            "vu" : "{{i.vu}}",
            "Mark" : "Yes",
            "Volume" : "{{tot_value}}"
            }
           {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
}
```

Please help me to resolve this....

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my `Azure liquid template`:

```
{% assign sky_name = "" %}
    {% assign tot_value = "" %}
    {
      "values": [
        {% for i in content.arrayvalues %}
            {% for properties in i.props %}
                {% if properties.find == "abc" %}
                {
                "id" : "{{i.id}}",
                "tot" : "{{i.tot}}",
                "vu" : "{{i.vu}}",
                "Mark" : "NO",
                "Volume" : "0"
                },
                {% assign sky_name = properties.sky %}
                {% assign tot_value = i.tot %}
                {% for j in content.arrayvalues %}
                    {% assign vu_name = j.vu %}
                    {% if vu_name == sky_name %}
                    {
                    "id" : "{{j.id}}",
                    "tot" : "{{j.tot}}",
                    "vu" : "{{j.vu}}",
                    "Mark" : "Yes",
                    "Volume" : "{{tot_value}}"
                    },
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your help. Its working fine